# Variable not getting updated in code running on mbed board

Tags: mbed

```js
 #include "mbed.h"
 
DigitalOut myled1(LED1);
DigitalOut myled2(LED2);
DigitalOut myled3(LED3);
DigitalOut myled4(LED4);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

int main() 
{ int c;
    while(1)
    {
    pc.scanf("%d",&c);
    pc.printf("hey i received %d",c);
    if (c==1050)
    {myled1=1;
    myled2=0;
    myled3=0;
    myled4=0;
    }
    else if (c==2050)
    {   myled1=0;
        myled4=0;
        myled3=0;
        myled2=1;
    }
    else if (c==3050)
    {myled3=1;
    myled4=0;
    myled2=0;
    myled1=0;
    }
    else if (c==4050)
    {myled4=1;
    myled3=0;
    myled2=0;
    myled1=0;
    }
    }
}
```

> The above code receives value of 'c' from terminal and takes decision based on the same. The issue I am facing is that when I use the printf, variabl c gets updated and the code runs properly otherwise not. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Serial data is transmitted one byte at a time. When you send a multiple digit integer by writing 1050 to the terminal, each number is sent individually. The function `getNumber()` below collects all bytes until carriage return is received. By subtracting the ASCII value of 48 (which is 0) the received character is converted to integer. The number is shifted left by multiplying with 10 before the received integer is added to it.

Best approach would be to use interrupts. See the example code below:

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut myled1(LED1);
DigitalOut myled2(LED2);
DigitalOut myled3(LED3);
DigitalOut myled4(LED4);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

unsigned int getNumber() 
{
    unsigned int val = 0;  // Max value 65535
    while(1)
    {
        char c = pc.getc();
        pc.putc(c); // echo back to terminal
        if (c == '\r') // enter pressed
            break;   
        val = ((c - 48) + (val * 10));
    }
    return val;
}

void callback() 
{
    unsigned int n = getNumber();
    pc.printf("Number = %d \r\n", n); // Write number to terminal
    if (n==1050)
    {
        myled1=1;
        myled2=0;
        myled3=0;
        myled4=0;
    }
    else if (n==2050)
    {   
        myled1=0;
        myled2=1;
        myled3=0;
        myled4=0;
    }
    else if (n==3050)
    {
        myled1=0;
        myled2=0;
        myled3=1;
        myled4=0;
    }
    else if (n==4050)
    {
        myled1=0;
        myled2=0;
        myled3=0;
        myled4=1;
    }
}

int main() {
    pc.attach(&callback);
    while (1) 
    {
        wait(0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Talamaki for your attention. I tried adding the delay of different time intervals but they only worked for 1 cycle. In successive cycles it seems to me that the value of number 'c' is not getting updated.

Comment: I added an example code using interrupts. Please, try it.

Comment: Actually I am trying to read a number.But i will surely try it to find the problem.

Comment: I tried the code that you provided and it works when modify my code for characters but my application requires me to receive a serial stream of numbers which I am still not able to receive properly without printf.

Comment: @RijoThomas I updated my answer based on your comment and included the example code which I tested by sending multiple digit integers to mbed board via terminal. The example echoes each digit back until enter is pressed and then prints the whole number to terminal.

Comment: I will try this code as it is and would update the result on stack in 2-3 days. Thank you. .It seems last time I did not copy paste this code ... and just used the concept. ..